# Change of coordinates for $X^3+Y^3+60Z^3=0$

Tags: algebraic-curves

I have to demonstrate that the curve
$$ X^3+Y^3+60Z^3=0$$
is birationally equivalent to 
$$Y^2=X^3-2^43^360^2$$ or to $$Y^2=X^3-3^330^2.$$ I can't find a proper change of coordinates for this purpose. Does anyone know how can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known that the Selmer curve 
$$  X^3 + Y^3 = dZ^3  $$
is birationally equivalent to Weierstrass curve 
$$  V^2W = U^3 - 2^4 3^3 d^2 W^3  $$
under the mutually inverse transformations $X= V - 36dW, Y= -V-36dW , Z=-6U$ along with $ U=12dZ, V= -36d(X-Y), W=X+Y $. My source for this is [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SmRinju-684C&pg=PA434&lpg=PA434&dq=Selmer+curve+is+birationally+equivalent+to+the+Weierstrass+curve&source=bl&ots=OJDji92aZH&sig=ACfU3U0e6umsYy_lao-PhQ-nk9tJo372LQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFxNa7_ITjAhVdSxUIHQpzBjkQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Selmer%20curve%20is%20birationally%20equivalent%20to%20the%20Weierstrass%20curve&f=false).

I think these will work with your case, i.e. $W=1$ and $d=-60$ though I'm not very well-versed in elliptic curves, so please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!